# How to add outliers to a Linear Regression dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to play around to see how outliers in a dataset might affect a Linear Regression model. The issue I'm having is I don't exactly know how to add outliers to a dataset, I've only found loads of articles online about how to detect and remove them.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression


# Generate regression dataset
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=1,
    noise=0.0,
    bias=0.0,
    random_state=42,
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  # Training the algorithm

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

print("R2 Score:", metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Mean Absolute Error:", metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Mean Squared Error:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error:", np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test)
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color="red", linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

And this is the output:

[image: Regression Model of Clean Dataset]

My question is how can I add outliers to this clean dataset in order to see the effects outliers will have on the resulting model?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just increase the noise parameter in make_regression

Comment: Hey, wouldn't adding noise to the data affect it in other ways as well? I just wanted to examine one factor which is how outliers impact the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add values directly to `X` and `y`.  Since the slope is significant enough, this will end up giving you outliers.   You could us any method you want really.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression


# Generate regression dataset
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=1,
    noise=0.0,
    bias=0.0,
    random_state=42,
)

for x in range(20):
    X=np.append(X, np.random.choice(X.flatten()))
    y=np.append(y, np.random.choice(y.flatten()))

X = X.reshape(-1,1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  # Training the algorithm

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

print("R2 Score:", metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Mean Absolute Error:", metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Mean Squared Error:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error:", np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test)
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color="red", linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]